# if condition is not functioning properly

Tags: c

i tried to make a calculator but could the compiler is checking my if conditions properly.
here is my code,
i could not figure out how to solve this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int first;
    int sec;
    char mode;
    printf("enter your forst number : ");
    scanf("%d",&first);
    printf("enter your second number : ");
    scanf("%d",&sec);
    printf("to add press      \"a\" \n");
    printf("to subtract press \"s\" \n"); 
    printf("to multiply press \"m\" \n");
    printf("to divide press   \"d\" \n");
    printf("so, what do you wanna do ");
    scanf(" %c",&mode); 
    printf("%d %d %s \n",first,sec,mode);

    if      (mode == 'a')
    {
        printf("%d \n",first + sec);
    }
    else if (mode == "s")
    {
        printf("%d \n",first-sec);
    }
    else if (mode == "m")
    {
        printf("%d \n",first*sec);
    }
    else if (mode == "d")
    {
        printf("%d \n",first/sec);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter a valid operation code \n");
    }
    
    
    
 
    return 0;
}

void def(char name[],int age)
{
    printf("het ur a %s and yo age is %i \n",name,age);
}
```

first attempt tried using a string instead of character (failed )
second attempt tried using a character but failed though!!

Comment: leave the code below the main function

Comment: `mode == "s"` Double quotes (`"`) make `s` a string.  This is one of your mistakes.

Comment: Did you look at your compiler's warnings? I'm seeing a bunch of these: *warning: comparison between pointer and integer*

Comment: thanks, but there are no compiler warnings i am getting

Comment: Unable to open 'strlen.S': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S'). [this is the warning given by my vs code ]

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: If you don't get warnings, you should enable more warnings. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: i am using this in my vs code and a ubuntu system. it will be using gcc compiler

Answer (score 0):

For comparing a single character in c, you must use single quotes. Consider an array of characters `array[4] = {'c','a','r','\0'}`;

```
if(array[0] == 'c'){
 //...
}
```

Comparing with double quotes, make the value inside it a string. For comparing strings you should `#include <strings.h>` and use the `strcmp` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

1. `mode == "s"` `mode` is a `char` so just use `mode == 's'` and do the same for others also.
2. `printf("%d %d %s \n",first,sec,mode);` should be `printf("%d %d %c \n",first,sec,mode);`

you are using `%s` for printing a `char`

Answer (score 0):

In your code "s" is a string not a caracter,to get a caracter you should write like this: 's'

here is the correction of your code :

```
int main()
{
    int first;
    int sec;
    char mode;
    printf("enter your forst number : ");
    scanf("%d",&first);
    printf("enter your second number : ");
    scanf("%d",&sec);
    printf("\nMenu : \n");
    printf("\nto add press      \"a\" \n");
    printf("to subtract press \"s\" \n");
    printf("to multiply press \"m\" \n");
    printf("to divide press   \"d\" \n");
    printf("so, what do you wanna do ");
    scanf(" %c", &mode);
    printf("%d %d %c \n",first,sec,mode);
    if(mode == 'a')
    {
        printf("%d \n",first + sec);
    }
    else if (mode == 's')
    {
        printf("%d \n",first-sec);
    }
    else if (mode == 'm')
    {
        printf("%d \n",first*sec);
    }
    else if (mode == 'd')
    {
       printf("%d \n",first/sec);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter a valid operation code \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```